Windows: not moving permissions when moving files on the same volume
For a service we are setting up, one of our Linux servers has a CIFS mount to one of our central storage servers, using a specific service account dedicated for this purpose. The remote directory is mounted to /mnt/server. The central storage server is Windows.
The application uses two main directories. The first one, /mnt/server/data has a specific DACL set from Windows, that gives full control to admins, read/write access to the service account, and read-only access to authorized users.
The second one is a special subdirectory named:  /mnt/server/data/tmp, which has a special DACL: the same as the other one, except no read access to users, admins full control, service account read-write, nothing else.
Files are created by an application in the tmp directory, and at some point moved out of tmp to a subdirectory that is read-accessible by users. Being a mv on the same volume, the operation is extremely fast even if files are huge, which is what we want.
The problem is that the ACLs inherited by the files when they are created are moved with the file, therefore making the newly generated files inaccessible from users,  which is not what we want.
It isn't practical to use setcifsacl on every moved file: (1) it can't work because the service user has only modify access, not full control (therefore it terminates with main: setxattr error: Permission denied), and (2) this seems overly complex and unreliable (imagine if the ACLs change because a new group of users need access: the application would need to be updated accordingly, instead of just relying on inheritance, so it's not desirable).
This behavior is caused by the Windows server, so it's not a peculiarity of mount.cifs. On Windows, it is apparently possible to tune the Explorer not to move the ACLs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/permissions-on-copying-moving-files
This doesn't help as the client runs Linux, and it even seems specific to Explorer rather than the file access itself.
Also related:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/inherited-permissions-not-automatically-update.
The only thing we came up with is to remove the special ACL from the tmp directory and to hide it, to prevent users from randomly browsing it. There's nothing sensitive inside, as files make their way into the readable part. It's  to keep things "clean".
I suspect the answer is "no". Is there any way of specifying that ACLs should not be "moved" with the file, without having to resort to a copy-and-delete operation that can take more time? We can't fix the flawed design of the permissions on the storage servers, but can updates ACLs and mount options on the client as needed.
